# Flutter : Provider error how to add new page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

Sorry, this is my first time using a provider
I don't know how to make the button take me to another page
I made a web page with filters
Main Screen

```
Scaffold(
  key: context.read<MenuController>().scaffoldKey,
  drawer: DrawerView(),
  body: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [

        if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            // default flex = 1
            // and it takes 1/6 part of the screen
            child: DrawerView(),
          ),
        // We want this side menu only for large screen

        Expanded(
          // It takes 5/6 part of the screen
          flex: 8,
          child: DashboardScreen(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
);
```

The page is divided into three parts
The provider part, the dashboard part, and the stats part

Menu Controller

```
    class MenuController extends ChangeNotifier {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> get scaffoldKey => _scaffoldKey;

  void controlMenu() {
    if (!_scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
    }
  }


}
```

main.dart

```
home: MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => MenuController(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MainScreen(),
  ),
```

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MainScreen Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on what you're trying to do but have you tried opening the drawer by doing this `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`?

Comment: iam using (onPressed: context.read<MenuController>().controlMenu)

Comment: @MediAhmed have you tried what I've suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare & implement provider like below

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => MenuController(),
            ),
          ],
          child: MainScreen(),
        );
      }
```